# Action creator data is not syncing correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I have an action creator using redux thunk and I'm getting something weird happening

take this code:

```
export const updateShowing = name => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log(getState().codeToRender.contents, 'first consolelog')
        const paramFound = getState().codeToRender.contents.find(param => param.name === name)
        console.log(paramFound, 'second consolelog')
        dispatch({ type: UPDATE_SHOWING, name })
        dispatch(push(`?${updateParamHelper(getState)}`))
    }
}
```

when I look inside the first console.log I'm getting the object with the key I'm looking for `render: true`

but the second console.log (where all I'm doing is a find on the same array), im getting `render: false` meaning at the same point in time for some reason I'm seeing 2 different values even through I'm accessing the same `getState`

any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE_SHOWING or the other action handler must be mutating state. Your console.logs look different because one probably shows element as is when it was logged and the other shows it as it is when you expand the console.

Try to run the following in the console:

```
const arr = [{name:'Ben'}];
console.log('expand and name is Jerry',arr);
console.log('as is when logged:',arr[0]);
arr[0].name='Jerry';
```

output example:

```
expand and name is Jerry  ▼[{…}]
                            ▶ 0:{name: "Jerry"}
                              length: 1
                            ▶ __proto__: Array(0)
as is when logged: {name: "Ben"}
```

You could change your console.logs to:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(getState().codeToRender.contents,undefined,2), 'first consolelog');
```

And you'll probably find that first and second console logs will log the same.

Comment: is this the whole thing with console logs in browsers not being an accurate representation ?

Comment: @RedBaron  You'll know for sure if you JSON.stringify the value you log. I don't see how it can be anything else, you have 2 console.logs after each other and no asynchronous code; however one has a different nested value than the other. The only way that happens is with the code I provided in the answer, the mutation must happen in the action handler: UPDATE_SHOWING or whatever action the push function returns.